# "Unable to retrieve database locations" error when setting up Google cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to setup Cloud Datastore, in GCP. Upon selecting "Cloud Datastore", in console, I see the "Choose where to store your data" page, with this error:

> "Unable to retrieve database locations
>   There was a problem retrieving the available storage locations for your data. Retry or return later to finish getting set up."

Has anybody encountered this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you still encountering this problem? Do you have a project selected when following [the steps](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/quickstart) to get started with Datastore?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherP. Yes, I'm still facing this. Yes, the project is selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have encountered same and resolved as below. (Iam using free tier)

When you select a location in either product (Cloud Datastore or App Engine), you set the location for your entire Google Cloud Platform project. I choose location to set from App Engine.

**From Home (on left side) --> App Engine --> Select a language (I have selected "python"). --> It prompts for location (I have selected "us-central") --> (press) Next**

Thats it come out of the tutorial. Next time I selected Datastore, it worked fine.

Hope this helps (screens below)

**SCREEN1**
[image: step1]

**SCREEN2**

[image: step2]

**SCREEN3**

[image: step3]

**SCREEN4**
[image: step4]

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar. It helped.

Comment: @ChristopherP, even though the workaround suggested by Sudhakar worked perfectly, this problem looks like a bug in Datastore: why should location be set via  App Engine and not Datastore directly?

Comment: @irahavoi, I have opened a bug with google, once resolved I will update this post with that info.

Comment: @irahavoi The bug (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113127311) seems to be resolved. I tested it and it works fine for me (letting user to select location at Datastore entity level). I would like to double check with you (if possible) as well before responding to google team.

Comment: Sudhakar, it's working fine for me as well now. Thanks for taking time submitting this to Google.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the exact same error. Some of the Google Cloud management tools are a bit buggy, gcloud included, they need more TLC and more users to report bugs to Google. The best way around the bugs is to either use the Firebase Console or the App Engine console. Either one of these two appear to be required to provide the missing management glue between the various Cloud products Google has. The Firebase console IMHO is superior to the app engine console, and that's what I would recommend using. You can create the DB from the Firebase console. it will also add Firebase to your project, giving you access to the Firebase CLI, which works very well and doesn't have all the bugs that gcloud CLI has.

1. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/ to open the firebase console
2. Click on `+Add Project` and select the project you created using the Google Cloud Console.
3. This will prompt you to `accept addind Firebase` for this project. Click `accept`, it will enable access to the project via the Firebase emulator and firebase CLI, you definitely want this.
4. Under `Develop` in the left hand menu, select `Database`, from there you will be able to add the version you want. Keep in mind only the old firestore has an SLA, but the new native Cloud Datastore is better, it has the pub/sub on events on read/writes.

I use Firebase to manage microservices that are only accessible via special routing from other backends and don't use any Firebase client code,  it's just so much easier to manage the functions and run them locally with the firebase emulator before deploying using the Firebase CLI. I've not had the same luck with gcloud or using the Google cloud console as opposed to the Firebase console. On the other hand, Firebase CLI, the emulator and the Firebase console are fantastic, pretty seamless experience. It's been a joy using them. I wish I could say the same about the Cloud console, I go in there only when truly necessary.